# How to prepare xml structure data for the checked items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stuck with small requirement. Here I have table with checkboxes.
Here I would like to check the rows and click on submit I would like to show the xml structuted data like below

```
<event>
    <count>2</count>
    <row>
        <evendid>test1</eventid>
    </row>
    <row>
        <evendid>test2</eventid>
    </row>
</event>
```

I tried with below code,

```
 $(".multipleData tbody tr").each(function() {
        bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "<row>";
        $(this).find('td checkbox').each(function() {                       
            $td = $(this);
            var tdValue = $(this).find("checkbox:checked").val();

            bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet +  tdValue;  
        });
        bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "</row>";
    });

    xml = xmlStart + xmlFirstRowSet + bodyRowSet+xmlLast;
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfjSG/1293/)

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but you have a closing `tbody` and never open it, also you have a lot of open `tr`s but never close one (in your jsFiddle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the input elements that are checked and then loop those:

```
var elements = $(".multipleData tr td input:checked");
```

And then for each found checked item, get the html from the td:

```
var tdValue = $(this).parent().next('td').html().trim();
```

Maybe this can help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#idXmlData").click(function(){
        var xmlStart =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\">";
        var xmlFirstRowSet = "<event>";
        var xmlLast="</event>";
        var headerRowSet='';
        xmlFirstRowSet = xmlFirstRowSet + headerRowSet;
        var bodyRowSet ='';

        var elements = $(".multipleData tr td input:checked");
        var size = elements.size();
        bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "<count>" + size + "</count>";
        elements.each(function() {
            var tdValue = $(this).parent().next('td').html().trim();
            bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "<row><eventid>";
            bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet +  tdValue;
            bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "</eventid></row>";
        });

        var xml = xmlStart + xmlFirstRowSet + bodyRowSet+xmlLast;
        window.alert(xml);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfjSG/1298/)